# Check if checkbox is checked and show text in span

Tags: jquery

I have a script that once a button is clicked it displays specified text in a span below.
How can I use this to check if a checkbox is checked and display text accordingly?
I've tried so many different ways to no avail. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/w5bdX/ 
A point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you miss `)` after `if ($('#checkbox-1').is(":checked"))`

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5bdX/1/)

Comment: How embarrassing.  Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

Just one small mistake, you are missing the closing bracket on the if statement.

You have:

```
if ($('#checkbox-1').is(":checked")
```

Should be

```
if ($('#checkbox-1').is(":checked"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#myCheckbox").click(function(e){
    if(this.is(":checked")){
         //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
```